# EF Core execute sql

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, .net-4.5

Am testing out Entity Framework Core, it's been well so far until i hit an error.
I am not able to execute sql from a DbSet with FromSql.
Error is 
dbset does not contain a definition for 'FromSql'
The code is

```
_context.Account.FromSql("Select * from dbo.Account");
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: why you have used C# 4.0 and not 4.5!?

Comment: It's C#  4.5, just verified

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It happened that I needed one more nuget package to get FromSql as well as Include to work.
I added this to my dependencies in the project.json file and after the restore, Voila.

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational": "1.0.0"
```

Works now

Comment: Just wanted to add that besides this dependency, we need to add "using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;" in the calling class and make sure that the version corresponds to the other ef core dependencies

Answer (score 6):

Please add namespace

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```